# Scraping Table & Printing various data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I currently have the following lines of code

```
import requests, re, bs4
from urllib.parse import urljoin
start_url = 'http://www.racingaustralia.horse/'

def make_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    return soup

def get_links(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"^/FreeFields/"))
    links = [urljoin(start_url,a['href']) for a in a_tags]
return links

def get_tds(link):
    soup = make_soup(link)
    tds = soup.find_all('td', class_="horse")
    for td in tds:
            print(td.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = get_links(start_url)
    for link in links:
        get_tds(link)
```

Which scrapes all horse names for meetings within the table from racingaustralia.com/horse

This is exactly what I want but I am also wanting the retrieve the date of the meeting, the location of the meeting and for each race, list the horse name.

This is an example of what I am wanting:

```
Date of Race Meet
Location of Race Meet
Race Number
Horse....
...
...
...
Race Number
Horse
...
...
etc
```

Would someone be able to help me adjust the code so that the date and location of each race meet is printed as well as the race number for each horse?

I have attempted the following, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do so.

```
def get_tds(link):
    soup = make_soup(link)
    race_date = soup.find_all('span', class_="race-venue-date")
    for span in race_date:
        print(span.text)

    tds = soup.find_all('td', class_="horse")
    for td in tds:
        print(td.text)

def get_info(link):
    item = soup.find_all('div', class_="top")
    for div in item:
        print(div.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = get_links(start_url)
    for link in links:
        get_info(link), get_tds(link)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I write the code above for you to understand how it work, you should not ask other people to write code for you.

Comment: Hi, you may have noticed I have actually adapted what code you wrote for me. I also had written a fair bit of code before you changed what I had. I am simply asking for assistance, if this is asking too much I will remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests, re, bs4
from urllib.parse import urljoin


def make_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    return soup

def get_links(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"^/FreeFields/"))
    links = [urljoin(start_url,a['href']) for a in a_tags]
    return links

def get_info(link):
    soup = make_soup(link)
    tds = soup.find_all('td', class_="horse")
    if tds:
        top = soup.find(class_="top").h2
        for s in top.stripped_strings:
            print(s)
        for index, td in enumerate(tds, 1):
            print(index, td.text, sep='\n')
    else:
        print('not find')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_url = 'http://www.racingaustralia.horse/'
    links = get_links(start_url)
    for link in links:
        get_info(link)
```

out:

```
Warwick Farm: Australian Turf Club
Wednesday, 18 January 2017
1
GAUGUIN (NZ) 
2
DAHOOIL (NZ) 
3
METAMORPHIC 
4
MY KIND 
5
CONCISELY 
6
ARAZONA 
7
APOLLO 
8
IGNITE THE LIGHT 
9
KRUPSKAYA
```

There are a lot URLs that does not contains the info you need, you should change the regex to filter it out, in this way, your code can run faster.

Comment: Hi, this result prints the horse number and not the race number. I'm not really wanting the horse number - just the race number.